# st_nn - turn list into data frame

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I'm working with some spatial data and I want to turn the output of the st_nn command (outputs a list) into a data frame that I can join. For example

```
library(nngeo)
library(data.table)

cities <- cities
towns <- towns

nearest <- st_nn(towns, cities, returnDist = TRUE, k = 1)
```

The output of the `nearest` list give me the unique ID of the nearest city and also the distance. I would like this as a tibble or data frame. Here is what I tried:

```
setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, nearest), c("col1", "col2"))
```

But this is not quite what I am looking for. I would like the a nearest city ID as one column and the distance to that city as the other column.

Comment: Perhaps something like this? `tibble(col1 = unlist(nearest[[1]]), col2 = unlist(nearest[[2]]))`?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad that this worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a more `tidyverse`-y approach, you can use/test the following code:

```r
library(nngeo)
library(purrr)

st_nn(towns, cities, returnDist = TRUE, k = 1) %>% 
  set_names("col1", "col2") %>% 
  map_df(., unlist)

#> # A tibble: 93 x 2
#>     col1   col2
#>    <int>  <dbl>
#>  1     3 53072.
#>  2     1 15069.
#>  3     3 33345.
#>  4     3 46392.
#>  5     3 57460.
#>  6     3 33249.
#>  7     3 25842.
#>  8     3 39434.
#>  9     1 23358.
#> 10     2 24749.
#> # … with 83 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is great! I came back to this post because I had a follow up. How would one approach turning this into a tibble with k=2. So the columns would be: (1) nearest_id, (2) nearest_distance,  (3) second_nearest_id,  (4) second_nearest_distance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is what you are looking for but from your `do.call` command, you can transpose it and convert as a dataframe:

```r
t <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, nearest)
t <- data.frame(t)
colnames(t) <- c("col1","col2")
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [nngeo- nearest neighbor with distance dataframe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356768/nngeo-nearest-neighbor-with-distance-dataframe), if you use `k>1`, you need a somehow more complex code. Here would be one code using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(nngeo)
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.3, PROJ 8.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)

nearest <- st_nn(towns[1:2,], cities, returnDist = TRUE, k = 3)
#> lon-lat points
#>   |                                                                              |                                                                      |   0%  |                                                                              |===================================                                   |  50%  |                                                                              |======================================================================| 100%

nn_to_df <- function(nn_out) {
  out <- map(names(nn_out), ~enframe(pluck(nn_out, .), name = "row_id", value = .) %>% 
               unnest(cols=all_of(.x))) 
  bind_cols(out[[1]], out[[2]] %>% select(-row_id))
}

nn_to_df(nn_out=nearest)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   row_id    nn    dist
#>    <int> <int>   <dbl>
#> 1      1     3  34147.
#> 2      1     2  76187.
#> 3      1     1  94717.
#> 4      2     3  18266.
#> 5      2     2  98838.
#> 6      2     1 130539.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>